# Verified Software Repository

Tags: program-verification, se.software-engineering

Does anyone know if the [verified software repository](http://vsr.sourceforge.net/) is still *alive*?  Bar that, are there other repositories out there of verified (or just certified) software?  The [archive of formal proofs](http://afp.sourceforge.net/) is nice, but not quite 'right'.

Finding singular examples of verified software is possible (with seL4 and CompCert being obvious examples), but finding whole groups of them is hard.  I would have expected to be able to find whole repositories of certified software components by now, but I have been unable to do so.

[While not TCS per se, the amount of underlying TCS issues involved in software verification/certification is enormous, so hopefully this will be considered to be on topic]